# How JRE/Eclipse decide which JRE jar is referenced

Tags: java, eclipse

When adding a JRE/JDK to an Eclipse project, under Project Explorer there is a "JRE System Library" node. Under this node:

(1) With JRE/JDK8, there is a list of jar files in the JRE/JDK, but some jars in the JRE/JDK install folder is not listed here (even for basic libraries in JRE_INSTALL_FOLDER\lib).

(2) With JDK9/JDK11, there is a list of module names which all points to jrt-fa.jar. I suppose the list still doesn't contains all modules in the JDK.

How does Eclipse/JRE(I suppose it is JRE that decide the list and Eclipse just show the list so when running the application out of Eclipse you still reference only those listed libraries in JRE) decide which libraries is contained in the list (both for JDK8 and JDK9+ which should use a different way)?

If the answer is based on some configuration file in JRE/JDK, then may be it is possible to remove some even more non essential libraries from the list by editing the config file.

Comment: To _JRE/JDK8_: do you talk about an _Exectuion Environment_ (shown as _JavaSE-1.8_) or a specific JRE?

Comment: @ howlger I mean the library you used in your Eclipse project, it is shown like "JRE System Library [jre1.8.0_111]"

Comment: So you mean a specific JRE (an _Exectuion Environment_ is shown as _JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]_). Can you give an example what is not listed? For Java 9+ only the active modules are shown and modules can be added or removed via _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Module Dependencies_ button _Add System Module..._ or by selection the module and hitting _Remove_. Additional JARs can be added to a JRE/JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ via _Edit..._ button.

Comment: @howlger for 1.8, deploy.jar/javaws.jar/jfxswt.jar/javaws.jar/tools.jar is not listed for example. For 9+ Im not sure since there are too many modules. The project is non-modular since Module Dependencies is gray.

Comment: For example, `tools.jar` is only contained in a JDK, not in a JRE. So if you want to use stuff of `tools.jar` (like e.g. Ant does it for `javac`), you have to add the JAR by configured the installed JRE globally for all projects (or add the JAR as project dependency): in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ select the JRE/JDK and click _Edit..._. In Java 9+, everything is contained in a single image file and the non-default modules have to be activated: in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Module Dependencies_ click _Add System Module..._ (= command line: `--add-modules`).